# CORS in IIS windows 10 not work

Tags: web-services, iis, cors

I have an aplication in IIS thet have a web service when i try access from other ip it response an error of Cross domain origin, in my web.config i have this lines:

```
<httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*"/>
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type"/>
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="POST,GET,OPTIONS"/>
    </customHeaders>
  </httpProtocol>
```

But it stilll fail when i try to send via post data to the webservice.

Comment: I have the same problem with IIS 10.

I have also tried the above approach, in my web.config, and the below in startup.cs

            app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);  However this did not solve the problem either.  

This is part of an API so I don't really want to specify where the request is coming from.

Comment: Did you ever find any solution for this?

Comment: Same here - under Win Server 2016, IIS-10, CORS not working. Server does not send the  'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header at all. Tried also using the Microsoft CORS module which has its own config section in web.config - no joy. Any solution found?